# Disabling date in JTCalendar in ios using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsdate, jtcalendar

Lets Say I have a date for lregistration of user and its 22/7/2016 No I want to only enable dates between 22/7/2016 and today.

Previous dates and future dates should be disabled How can I do that ?

Comment: Have u want it in JTCalender or in UIDatePicker?

Comment: I want this behaviour in JTCalendar

Comment: Did you solve it?